# MuleSoft Proxy Settings not working for AMAZON SQS

Tags: mule

We are trying to connect with amazon SQS from our corporate network. But its throwing below error

I have added  Proxy details

1. VM Arguments in Run configurations:

   - Dhttp.proxyHost=rb-proxy-apac.bosch.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=prd5kor -Dhttp.proxyPassword=
   - Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true
2. Global Element properties:HTTP-HTTPS--->Proxy Settings
3. Prefernces-->General-->Network Connections( Active Provider-Manual)

Mule Config.XML:

```
`<http:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="rfc2109" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" proxyHostname="rb-proxy-apac.bosch.com" proxyPort="8080" proxyUsername="prd5kor" proxyPassword="Bibhushree@12345" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS"/>
    <sqs:config name="SQS_AMAZON" accessKey="------" secretKey="-----" queueName="bibhushree" doc:name="Amazon SQS"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer name="File_to_String" doc:name="File to String"/>
    <flow name="sqs_projectFlow2" doc:name="sqs_projectFlow2">
        <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="bmhe321649.BMH.APAC.BOSCH.COM" port="21" path="/MULE" user="prd5kor" password="------" responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="File_to_String" doc:name="FTP"/>
        <sqs:send-message config-ref="SQS_AMAZON" queueUrl="https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/189129605181/bibhushree" accessKey="-----" secretKey="---------" queueName="bibhushree" doc:name="Amazon SQS"/>
        <logger message="Received a message: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`
```

Error:

```
`java.net.UnknownHostException: sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:402)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:245)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2221)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.createQueue(AmazonSQSClient.java:1150)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.SQSConnector.connect(SQSConnector.java:102)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectorConnectionFactory.makeObject(SQSConnectorConnectionFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectorConnectionManager.acquireConnection(SQSConnectorConnectionManager.java:254)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectorConnectionManager.acquireConnection(SQSConnectorConnectionManager.java:40)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.RetryProcessInterceptor.execute(RetryProcessInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.ManagedConnectionProcessTemplate.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessTemplate.java:35)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.processors.SendMessageMessageProcessor.doProcess(SendMessageMessageProcessor.java:131)
    at org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.process(DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.java:86)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:118)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:189)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:182)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExec...`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the SQS [connector](https://github.com/mulesoft/sqs-connector/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mule/modules/sqs/SQSConnector.java) doesn't seems to honor the proxy settings.
I've just raised an [issue](https://github.com/mulesoft/sqs-connector/issues/24) on the project around this.